# heap corruption in c++

Tags: c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I'm getting an error in runtime when I run my code in visual c++ 2010.

```
void dct2(){
    float** G = new float*[len];
    for(int u = 0; u < len; u++){
        G[u] = new float[len];
        for(int v = 0; v < len; v++){
            G[u][v] = 0;
            for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
                for(int y = 0; y < len; y++){
                    G[u][v] += a(u) * a(v) * (float)mat[x][y] * cos((PI / 8) * u * (x + 0.5)) * cos((PI / 8) * v * (y + 0.5));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doublecpy(G);
}
void doublecpy(float** d){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
            if(d[i][j] >= 0)
                mat[i][j] = (int)(d[i][j] + 0.5);
            else
                mat[i][j] = (int)(d[i][j] - 0.5);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        delete[] d[i];
    delete[] d;
}
```

the error comes in the line: delete[] d[i];
please tell me if there's anything wrong with this piece of code or any advice.

Comment: It seems ok. Is len truly a constant ? Its modification is the only evident thing I spot, besides more complex heap corruption ...

Comment: are you sure that `mat` has correct size and allocation? Didn't you write out of it range?

Comment: Advice asked (sorry, no direct solutions): 1) try to delete in the same scope as you new (now, doublecpy() has serious side-effects). 2) avoid new/delete by using std::vector

Comment: holly crap. That code looks awful.

Comment: You should tag it as C : array, massive explicit heap allocation, casts... Nothing c++

Comment: I am sure everybody loves reading code that is completely unreadable. Variable names can be longer than 1 character (this is not a golf forum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started converting all arrays to std::vector and in the midway i ran the code. That didn't solve my problem but i found the cause of the error. it was in this function:

```
void cpy(int** arr, int x, int y){
    for(int i = x; i < x + len; i++){
        for(int j = y; j < y + len; j++){
            mat[i][j] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The mistake is very visible, i corrected it:

```
void cpy(int** arr, int x, int y){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
            mat[i][j] = arr[i + x][j + y];
        }
    }
}
```

Although this is very weird. I expected to receive an "array index out of bound" or "segmentation fault" when running the wrong code in the line: mat[i][j] = arr[i][j];

Anyways thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact you should not write C++ this way (this is just C with new instead of malloc) I can't see any memory errors but do not know what mat is and how it was allocated.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your discrete cosine transform and butterfly code to fit my C compiler (not C++). I inserted dummy-functions and constants for those that i dont have. It works (i tested it up to len=1000) without corrupting memory. The reason my version works **may be** `new float*[len]`, which you could rewrite to `malloc(len*sizeof(float*))` to try out if that was the problem.

(I dont have a c++-compiler handy to try it myself)
By the way, i find it intersting that you `new` in dct2() but `delete` in doublecpy().

Anyway. This is my adapted code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define len 1000
    #define PI 3.14

    float mat[len][len];

    float a(int u) {
            return 1.0;
    }

    void doublecpy(float** d){
            int i;
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    int j;
            for(j = 0; j < len; j++){
                if(d[i][j] >= 0)
                    mat[i][j] = (int)(d[i][j] + 0.5);
                else
                    mat[i][j] = (int)(d[i][j] - 0.5);
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            free(d[i]);
        free(d);
    }


    void dct2(){
        float** G = malloc(len*sizeof(float*));//new float* [len];
        int u;
        for(u = 0; u < len; u++){
            G[u] = malloc(len*sizeof(float));
            int v;
            for(v = 0; v < len; v++){
                G[u][v] = 0;
                int x;
                for(x = 0; x < len; x++){
                                    int y;
                    for(y = 0; y < len; y++){
                        G[u][v] += a(u) * a(v) * (float)mat[x][y] * cos((PI / 8) * u * (x + 0.5)) * cos((PI / 8) * v * (y + 0.5));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        doublecpy(G);
    }
    int main()
    {
            dct2();
            getch();
    }
```

Comment: I agree. If you are going to write in C, then do so and use malloc and free.

Comment: BTW, if you really want to use the DCT function, that's not how the function a() is defined.

Comment: and i guess PI is not exactly 3.14 :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment, I can not see anything wrong ...

Try tools like [duma](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) to check for corruption ...

my2c